# Laplace transform of a time domain sampled data

Tags: laplace-transform, matlab

I have a one second voltage data sampled with 4000Hz and I can plot the voltage vs time in MATLAB. So it means I have a data matrix with with length of 4000 one column for the time in seconds the other for the voltage.

How can I take the Laplace transform of this data?
Can I do it without converting it to a expressible function like poly-fit?

Comment: You can't. In order to define the Laplace transform, you need a model. What you can do it apply model identification to get a model. I don't know exactly what you want, but perhaps `semilogy(abs(fft(x)))` does the job for you.

Comment: I have two sampled data in time domain. One is input to a filter the other is output. Like Vin(t) and V(out). I want to find the transfer function both for amplitude and phase shift.

Comment: If you want to find the transfer function, you need to use system identification. Do you whether the filter is linear. If yes, this might help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/gs/identify-linear-models-using-the-gui.html

Comment: Yes it is quite linear.

Comment: But I have one input and one output data in time. So should I convert them one by one first by Laplace transform with this tool?

Comment: Actually I never used that tool, so I can't help you with that. But what you basically have to do is to find a transfer function that "explains" your data. You can also have a look at the system identification toolbox. If you have an idea of the number of poles and zeros and the delay, then this might be useful: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/arx.html

Answer (score 0):

divide fft of output by fft of input?

data may be noisey, may need windowing or trimming to avoid fft's spectral spreading with non exact periodic record

much more sophisticated system identification tools exist but I did just that to fit to a low order model in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407051/suggestions-for-fitting-noisy-exponentials-with-scipy-curve-fit/42500533#42500533[image]

Comment: How can I plot the phase of the transfer function by FFT in MATLAB?

Comment: the point by point division of the fft is a complex valued 1d array [magnitude  phase matlab](https://www.google.com/search?q=magnitude+phase+matlab&oq=magnitude+phase+matlab&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i60j69i61.23704j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)